# ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript

I've written a few lines of ajax code that work, but it also provides following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of
>   null
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange

The point is that this Error shows me 2 times and the first time status = 2 is the second time status = 3.

**Code:**

```
function ajax_XML(){
        var request;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        request.open('GET','ajax.xml');
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
                var items = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Name');

                var output = "<ul>";

                for(var i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
                    output+="<li>" + items[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>"
                }
                output+="</ul>";
                document.getElementById('ajax_xml').innerHTML=output;
            }else{
                console.log('error');
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }
```

**[This is the link to the ajax file that is attached to the question.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfq3z3-KmZenvCanS3D86cT256-5VLAG/view)**

Comment: What do you get when you use `console.log(request.responseXML)`?

Comment: Your `request.responseXML` is `null`, maybe you'd add a check to your `if` statement to account for that.

Comment: @Tien Duong - I use it inside the bet and it returns the contents of the file to me

Comment: `ajax.xml` is not properly formatted - perhaps it has a BOM marker ?

Comment: @IVO GELOV  -  
What's your solution?

Comment: Provide a link to `ajax.xml` so we can check.

Comment: @IVO GELOV - I have attached a link to the question that shows the .xml file

Comment: @jhon link is broken... upload it to a file sharing site or something.

Comment: @IVO GELOV - I change the link,please try again

Comment: It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for showing the error, I used to have exactly the same code but it didn't show any errors because there is no code to show the error but in the above code ELSE indicates an error, in fact all the code as written They have this error because most XML tags do not exist in HTML and that is the reason for this error.
**The code should not be written to indicate the error**

```
function ajax_XML(){
        var request;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        request.open('GET','ajax.xml');
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
                var items = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Name');

                var output = "<ul>";

                for(var i = 0;i<items.length;i++){
                    output+="<li>" + items[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>"
                }
                output+="</ul>";
                document.getElementById('ajax_xml').innerHTML=output;
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }
```